# Is there a way to set the brightness of my desktop PC using key shortcuts?

Tags: 11.04, shortcut-keys, brightness

I don't really know what relevant information to post here...

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 with unity enabled using free drivers for the Nvidia card FX-5200 256MB (private drivers don't work).

I'm using an 19" LG monitor which has a brightness configuration menu, but changing is kind of annoying, and takes a lot longer that if I had a key command. So, can I set a shortcut to set brightness level from the keyboard like as I were using a laptop?

Answer (score 2):

If your monitor implements the backlight property, you can adjust it with the `xbacklight` tool. `xbacklight -inc 10%` increases backlight by 10%, and `xbacklight -dec 10%` decreases it. However, it will not work unless the monitor explicitly support it, like laptop displays without built-in controls does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible since the brightness levels are controlled and manipulated within the monitor. I could be wrong but I believe that the operating system cannot control that.

Comment: Well, brightness obbeys to the HSI (or RGB with a simple conversion) color model, modifying the Intensity is quite easy since it is a simple rest to the value of the color. So, pc should send that modified information (that's what made me think about this possible), but you may be right, I don't know. Maybe for performance issues in the CPU that control rests on the monitor as you say. However, I hope you are wrong ;) thanks for answering, you have a good point.

Comment: Not a problem. It would be very nice if I was wrong though, and I'm monitoring (see what I did there?) this page, because if it can be done, I would like to use that information as well.